# ZFS Send to Pigz, to netcat

Tags: zfs, netcat

I am writing a script that opens a `netcat` process remotely on a server which listens for input and redirects it to a file:

`ssh $remote_upload_user@remote_upload_address "nc -l -p $remote_port > $remote_dir/$backup.gz&"`

The script proceeds to compress the ZFS snapshot through `pigz` and then sends the data as input to `netcat`:

`netcat $remote_upload_address -u $remote_port < $(zfs send -R $zpool@label | pigz)`

When adding `|pv` to the end of `pigz` (within the parentheses) it shows that `pigz` is processing the data, but once the data passes to `netcat` I get a never ending stream of garbled data flooding stdout on the client side.

The server shows 0 size in increase for the file it needs to be writing to. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$(...)` is command substitution. You don't want the output of `zfs send` to be taken as a file name for `nc` to read from. You want to send the output of `zfs send` as input to `pigz` while `pigz` sends its output to `netcat`, so:

```
zfs send -R "$zpool@label" | pigz | netcat "$remote_upload_address" "$remote_port"
```

Don't use UDP. UDP, contrary to TCP provides no guarantee of delivery.

If you wanted to use the `<` redirection operator, you could use `ksh`-style *process* substitution (also found in `zsh` and `bash`):

```
netcat "$remote_upload_address" "$remote_port" < <(
  zfs send -R "$zpool@label" | pigz)
```

But that has no advantage over the standard `|`-based equivalent. There, the file name passed to the `<` redirection operator is a named pipe or `/dev/fd/x` special file that points to a pipe (`pigz` writing at the other end of the pipe).

That's the same but involves a few extra system calls. Another difference is that the shell doesn't wait for that `zfs send|pigz` command (though it waits for `netcat` which probably won't terminate before `pigz` as it's reading its output).

Or use `yash`'s process redirection operator:

```
netcat "$remote_upload_address" "$remote_port" <(
  zfs send -R "$zpool@label" | pigz)
```

Again, no advantage over the standard syntax here. You'd typically use process redirection in `yash` when you want to have several fds of a command connected to pipes to other commands.